# How to extract values between 2 or more special characters using regex in R?

Tags: r, regex

```
string_1 = "[1] \"  .. ..$ : chr [1, 1] \\\"DM_4CRSOL\\\"\""
```

How to extract 'DM_4CRSOL' from string_1 using regex in R?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/bC7ToD/2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like to expand on romles answer:

```
#install.packages("stringi")
library(stringi)
string_1 = "[1] \"  .. ..$ : chr [1, 1] \\\"DM_4CRSOL\\\"\""
stri_extract(string_1, regex = '(?<=\\\\").*(?=\\\\")')
```

gives

```
[1] "DM_4CRSOL"
```

Answer (score 2):

This does the task:
`stringi::stri_extract(string_1, regex = '(?<=\\\\").*(?=\\\\")')`

Comment: Works good, thanks :)